# Does the On Demand Flight Status API production response include text string status?

Tags: amadeus

Does the On Demand Flight Status API production response include text string status, such as scheduled, en-route, cancelled, delayed? It appears to only include a delay value, if there is one.

I'm not finding that in the documentation. Thank you.